# RSA encrypt in iOS, decrypt in node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, rsa

I used https://github.com/xjunior/XRSA (refer to this: http://blog.iamzsx.me/show.html?id=155002) library to encrypt data in iOS,
but the encrypted data cannot be decrypted in node.js, neither with ursa lib nor crypto.createDecipher method.

The public key is in der format, and the header of private key is something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,5B61CF6591CD5C11
```

In iOS with XRSA lib, the information is encrypted in this way:

```
XRSA *rsa = [[XRSA alloc] initWithPublicKey:@"some path"];

NSString* lEncrypted = [rsa encryptToString:@"text needed to be encrypted"];
```

and then with URSA nodejs module, it returned:

```
return encodeBuffer(rsa.privateDecrypt(buf, padding), outEncoding);
                        ^
Error: error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error
```

is that possible for this kind of private key used in node.js for decrypting something?

Comment: Are you adding padding when encryption, that is really required. Is the data short enough?

Comment: the data is plain text, around 20 characters

Comment: Are you adding padding when encrypting?

Comment: @BossaGroove were you able to solve this issue?